# View pager loop with arraylist object error unknown

Tags: java, android

I just finished a small code, but it has a bug and I do not know why the error. My code

```html
package com.creativei.viewpagerloop;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 private static final String LOG_TAG = "ViewPagerLoop";
 private Button btn;
 static ArrayList<data> arraydt = new ArrayList<data>();
 ArrayList<data> str = new ArrayList<data>();

 int Cur = 1;
 static int lastPage = 1;
 Button btnUp, btnDown;
 static int nextId;
 int id = 2;
 private ViewPager pager;
 private Fragment fragment1;
 private ArrayList<data> arraydt1 = new ArrayList<data>();

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  str.add(new data("0", "hello0"));
  str.add(new data("1", "hello1"));
  str.add(new data("2", "hello2"));
  str.add(new data("3", "hello3"));
  str.add(new data("4", "hello4"));
  str.add(new data("5", "hello5"));
  str.add(new data("6", "hello6"));
  str.add(new data("7", "hello7"));
  str.add(new data("8", "hello8"));
  str.add(new data("9", "hello9"));

  arraydt.add(new data("1", "hello0"));
  arraydt.add(new data("2", "hello1"));
  arraydt.add(new data("3", "hello2"));

  pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
  TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
  btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      .show();
   }
  });
  SimpleViewPagerAdapter adapter = new SimpleViewPagerAdapter(this,
    getSupportFragmentManager(), pager, counter, arraydt);
  pager.setAdapter(adapter);
  pager.setOnPageChangeListener(adapter);
  pager.setCurrentItem(2, false);

  pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

   private Object fragment;

   @Override
   public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (position == 0) {
     pager.setCurrentItem(arraydt.size(), false);
     nextId = 1;
     Log.d("position0", "00000");
    } else if (position == arraydt.size() + 1) {
     pager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
     nextId = 3;
     Log.d("position" + position, "" + position);
    }

    // if (nextId == 0)
    if (nextId == 1) {

     if (position == 2) {
      id++;
      if (id == str.size()) {
       id = 0;
      }
      Log.d("+12 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
      arraydt.set(2, str.get(id));
      Log.d("ArrayDT", "   0: " + arraydt.get(0).getText()
        + "   1: " + arraydt.get(1).getText() + "  2: "
        + arraydt.get(2).getText());
     } else if (position == 3) {
      id--;
      if (id < 0) {
       id = str.size() - 1;
      }
      Log.d("-13 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
     }
    } else if (nextId == 2) {
     if (position == 3) {
      id++;
      if (id == str.size()) {
       id = 0;
      }
      Log.d("+23 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
      arraydt.set(0, str.get(id));
      Log.d("ArrayDT", "   0: " + arraydt.get(0).getText()
        + "   1: " + arraydt.get(1).getText() + "  2: "
        + arraydt.get(2).getText());
     } else if (position == 1) {
      id--;
      if (id < 0) {
       id = str.size() - 1;
      }
      Log.d("-21 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
     }
    } else if (nextId == 3) {
     if (position == 1) {
      id++;
      if (id == str.size()) {
       id = 0;
      }
      Log.d("+31 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
      arraydt.set(1, str.get(id));
      Log.d("ArrayDT", "   0: " + arraydt.get(0).getText()
        + "   1: " + arraydt.get(1).getText() + "  2: "
        + arraydt.get(2).getText());
     } else if (position == 2) {
      id--;
      if (id < 0) {
       id = str.size() - 1;
      }
     }
    }
    nextId = pager.getCurrentItem();
    Log.d("CURRENTUITEM", "" + pager.getCurrentItem());

   }

   @Override
   public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
  });

 }

 public static class SimpleFragment extends Fragment {
  private int position;
  private TextView tv;
  private int id1;
  private LinearLayout llayout;

  public SimpleFragment() {
   // this.position=postiton;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
     false);
   // String content1 = getArguments().getString("content");
   id1 = getArguments().getInt("position");

   
   // int id = Integer.parseInt(content1);
   // Log.d("Content", content1);
   llayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Llayout);
   llayout.removeAllViews();
   tv = new TextView(getActivity());

   tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   Log.d("Oncreate", "" + id1 + "  "
     + arraydt.get(id1).getText().toString());
   tv.setText(arraydt.get(id1).getText().toString() + " " + (id1));
   Log.d("TextView", ""
     + tv.getText().toString());
   llayout.addView(tv);

   return rootView;

  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onResume();
   llayout.removeAllViews();
   id1 = getArguments().getInt("position");
   tv = new TextView(getActivity());
   tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   tv.setText(arraydt.get(id1).getText().toString() + " " + (id1));
   Log.d("TV", tv.getText().toString() + " "
     + arraydt.get(0).getText().toString() + " "
     + arraydt.get(1).getText().toString() + " "
     + arraydt.get(2).getText().toString());
   Log.d("TV", tv.getText().toString() + " "
     + arraydt.get(id1).getText().toString());
   llayout.addView(tv);
   Log.d("ONRESUM", "ONRESUM");
  }
 }

 public static class SimpleViewPagerAdapter extends
   FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements OnPageChangeListener {
  private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
  private ArrayList<data> arraydt;
  private String[] content;
  private ViewPager pager;
  private TextView counter;
  private Context context;
  private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

  public SimpleViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm,
    ViewPager pager, TextView counter, ArrayList<data> arraydt) {

   super(fm);
   mFragmentManager = fm;
   this.pager = pager;
   this.counter = counter;
   this.arraydt = arraydt;
   mFragmentTags = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
   this.context = context;

  }

  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
   Object ojb = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
   if (ojb instanceof Fragment) {
    Fragment f = (Fragment) ojb;
    String tag = f.getTag();
    mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
   }

   return ojb;
  }

  public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
   String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
   if (tag == null) {
    return null;
   }
   return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   SimpleFragment fragment = new SimpleFragment();

   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   int index;
   if (position == 0) {
    index = arraydt.size() - 1;
    Log.d("OK", "OK0");
   } else if (position == arraydt.size() + 1) {
    index = 0;
    Log.d("OK", "OK4");
   } else {
    index = position - 1;
    Log.d("OK", "OK" + index);
   }

   bundle.putInt("position", index);
   fragment.setArguments(bundle);

   return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   return arraydt.size() + 2;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
   Log.d("nextId", "" + position);
   nextId = position;

  }

  private String makeCounterText(int pageNo) {
   return "Page " + pageNo + " of " + arraydt.size();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
   Toast.makeText(context, "arg0: " + arg0, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
  }

 }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```html
package com.creativei.viewpagerloop;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 private static final String LOG_TAG = "ViewPagerLoop";
 private Button btn;
 static ArrayList<data> arraydt = new ArrayList<data>();
 ArrayList<data> str = new ArrayList<data>();

 int Cur = 1;
 static int lastPage = 1;
 Button btnUp, btnDown;
 static int nextId;
 int id = 2;
 private ViewPager pager;
 private Fragment fragment1;
 private ArrayList<data> arraydt1 = new ArrayList<data>();

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  str.add(new data("0", "hello0"));
  str.add(new data("1", "hello1"));
  str.add(new data("2", "hello2"));
  str.add(new data("3", "hello3"));
  str.add(new data("4", "hello4"));
  str.add(new data("5", "hello5"));
  str.add(new data("6", "hello6"));
  str.add(new data("7", "hello7"));
  str.add(new data("8", "hello8"));
  str.add(new data("9", "hello9"));

  arraydt.add(new data("1", "hello0"));
  arraydt.add(new data("2", "hello100"));
  arraydt.add(new data("3", "hello2"));

  pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
  TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
  btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      .show();
   }
  });
  SimpleViewPagerAdapter adapter = new SimpleViewPagerAdapter(this,
    getSupportFragmentManager(), pager, counter, arraydt);
  pager.setAdapter(adapter);
  pager.setOnPageChangeListener(adapter);
  pager.setCurrentItem(2, false);

  pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

   private Object fragment;

   @Override
   public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (position == 0) {
     pager.setCurrentItem(arraydt.size(), false);
     nextId = 1;
     Log.d("position0", "00000");
    } else if (position == arraydt.size() + 1) {
     pager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
     nextId = 3;
     Log.d("position" + position, "" + position);
    }

    // if (nextId == 0)
    if (nextId == 1) {

     if (position == 2) {
      id++;
      if (id == str.size()) {
       id = 0;
      }
      Log.d("+12 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
      arraydt.set(2, str.get(id));
      Log.d("ArrayDT", "   0: " + arraydt.get(0).getText()
        + "   1: " + arraydt.get(1).getText() + "  2: "
        + arraydt.get(2).getText());
     } else if (position == 3) {
      id--;
      if (id < 0) {
       id = str.size() - 1;
      }
      Log.d("-13 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
     }
    } else if (nextId == 2) {
     if (position == 3) {
      id++;
      if (id == str.size()) {
       id = 0;
      }
      Log.d("+23 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
      arraydt.set(0, str.get(id));
      Log.d("ArrayDT", "   0: " + arraydt.get(0).getText()
        + "   1: " + arraydt.get(1).getText() + "  2: "
        + arraydt.get(2).getText());
     } else if (position == 1) {
      id--;
      if (id < 0) {
       id = str.size() - 1;
      }
      Log.d("-21 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
     }
    } else if (nextId == 3) {
     if (position == 1) {
      id++;
      if (id == str.size()) {
       id = 0;
      }
      Log.d("+31 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
      arraydt.set(1, str.get(id));
      Log.d("ArrayDT", "   0: " + arraydt.get(0).getText()
        + "   1: " + arraydt.get(1).getText() + "  2: "
        + arraydt.get(2).getText());
     } else if (position == 2) {
      id--;
      if (id < 0) {
       id = str.size() - 1;
      }
     }
    }
    nextId = pager.getCurrentItem();
    Log.d("CURRENTUITEM", "" + pager.getCurrentItem());

   }

   @Override
   public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
  });

 }

 public static class SimpleFragment extends Fragment {
  private int position;
  private TextView tv;
  private int id1;
  private LinearLayout llayout;

  public SimpleFragment() {
   // this.position=postiton;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
     false);
   // String content1 = getArguments().getString("content");
   id1 = getArguments().getInt("position");

   
   // int id = Integer.parseInt(content1);
   // Log.d("Content", content1);
   llayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Llayout);
   llayout.removeAllViews();
   tv = new TextView(getActivity());

   tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   Log.d("Oncreate", "" + id1 + "  "
     + arraydt.get(id1).getText().toString());
   tv.setText(arraydt.get(id1).getText().toString() + " " + (id1));
   Log.d("TextView", ""
     + tv.getText().toString());
   llayout.addView(tv);

   return rootView;

  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onResume();
   llayout.removeAllViews();
   id1 = getArguments().getInt("position");
   tv = new TextView(getActivity());
   tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   tv.setText(arraydt.get(id1).getText().toString() + " " + (id1));
   Log.d("TV", tv.getText().toString() + " "
     + arraydt.get(0).getText().toString() + " "
     + arraydt.get(1).getText().toString() + " "
     + arraydt.get(2).getText().toString());
   Log.d("TV", tv.getText().toString() + " "
     + arraydt.get(id1).getText().toString());
   llayout.addView(tv);
   Log.d("ONRESUM", "ONRESUM");
  }
 }

 public static class SimpleViewPagerAdapter extends
   FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements OnPageChangeListener {
  private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
  private ArrayList<data> arraydt;
  private String[] content;
  private ViewPager pager;
  private TextView counter;
  private Context context;
  private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

  public SimpleViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm,
    ViewPager pager, TextView counter, ArrayList<data> arraydt) {

   super(fm);
   mFragmentManager = fm;
   this.pager = pager;
   this.counter = counter;
   this.arraydt = arraydt;
   mFragmentTags = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
   this.context = context;

  }

  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
   Object ojb = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
   if (ojb instanceof Fragment) {
    Fragment f = (Fragment) ojb;
    String tag = f.getTag();
    mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
   }

   return ojb;
  }

  public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
   String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
   if (tag == null) {
    return null;
   }
   return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   SimpleFragment fragment = new SimpleFragment();

   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   int index;
   if (position == 0) {
    index = arraydt.size() - 1;
    Log.d("OK", "OK0");
   } else if (position == arraydt.size() + 1) {
    index = 0;
    Log.d("OK", "OK4");
   } else {
    index = position - 1;
    Log.d("OK", "OK" + index);
   }

   bundle.putInt("position", index);
   fragment.setArguments(bundle);

   return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   return arraydt.size() + 2;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
   Log.d("nextId", "" + position);
   nextId = position;

  }

  private String makeCounterText(int pageNo) {
   return "Page " + pageNo + " of " + arraydt.size();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
   Toast.makeText(context, "arg0: " + arg0, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
  }

 }
}
```

fragment_main.xml

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.creativei.viewpagerloop.SimpleFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Llayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It failed to repeat to the second element of view pager. I log out of a text view value before and after the lightning, I see it's still true but when it display in text view, the value that is a different value. Where errors?

Comment: Would you narrow down the problem a bit, perhaps by building the smallest possible demo demonstrating this problem? As it stands there is a lot of code here for someone to wade through.

Comment: I dit it, thank you.